# Is it possible to allow navigation away from a page when waiting for a JsonResult?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, jsonresult

In an MVC system, I am using Json calls to read information from my database. Some of these calls take some time to complete. Specifically when reading information for kendo grids. While the grids are reading their information from the database, navigation away from the page is 'locked'. Any attempts to navigate away will not execute until the grid is done reading data. This makes the page seem unresponsive.

I want to allow navigation away from the page while these data reads are being ran, abandoning the reads preferably.

Is this possible?

Here are some code snip-its in case it helps.

The data call:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: { url: "/Clients/ReadClientQuotes", data: { clientId: @ViewBag.clientId, quoteNum: $("#ddSearch").val(), zip: $("#ddvalue").val() }, datatype: "jsonp" }
            },
            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                }
            },
            schema: {   
                data: "result",
                total: function (data) {
                    return data.result.length;
                },
                model: {
                    id: "id",
                    fields: {
                        quoteNum: { editable: false },
                        insuredName: { editable: false },
                        locationAddress: { editable: false },
                        city: { editable: false },
                        state: { editable: false },
                        status: { editable: false },
                        effDate: { editable: false },
                        expDate: { editable: false },
                        contactName: {editable: false},
                        zip: {editable: false}
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 15
        });
```

The controller action:

```
public JsonResult ReadClientQuotes(int clientId, string searchby = "", string searchbyvalue = "")
    {

        if (clientId != 0)
        {

            ViewBag.test = "test";

            var quotes = _quoteServices.QuoteSearchForClient(clientId, searchby, searchbyvalue);

            StateLookUpDto blankState = new StateLookUpDto();
            blankState.Name = "no state";

            QuoteStatusDto nullStatusDto = new QuoteStatusDto();
            nullStatusDto.Status = "null";

            var results = quotes.Select(quote => new
            {
                quote.Id,
                quote.QuoteNum,
                insuredName = quote.ClientDto.FirstName + " " + quote.ClientDto.LastName,
                locationAddress = quote.PAddress1,
                city = quote.PCity.HasValue() ? quote.PCity : "",
                state = (_dropDownServices.GetStateById(quote.PStateId ?? 0) ?? blankState).Code,
                status = (quote.QuoteStatusDto ?? nullStatusDto).Status,
                effDate = (quote.EffectiveDate ?? DateTime.MinValue).ToString("d"),
                expDate = quote.RatedDate != null ? Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(quote.RatedDate).AddDays(30)).ToShortDateString() : "incomplete",
                zip = quote.PZip ?? ""
            });
            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        var emptyResult = new
        {
                quoteID = 0,
                quoteNum = "",
                insuredName = "",
                locationAddress = "",
                city = "",
                state = "",
                status = "",
                effDate = "",
                expDate = "",
                quoteDate = ""

        };

        return Json(emptyResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: I don't know much about how Kendo works (I've never used it), but I can tell you off-hand that this is not an MVC question--it's a Kendo one. Your server framework will have no impact on how the client UI is rendered. I'm just letting you know this so you can think about the problem differently (and perhaps ask it differently). The "problem" is likely in the browser itself, and everything is behaving as expected (it's using the UI thread to update the UI, thus blocking other interactions). So it's up to you or Kendo to modify how it performs those threaded actions.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information.